# Selenium - FileNotFound in OpenFileDialog

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

After clicking a button on a page, a file dialog opens up.

I wrote the following code to send keys:

```
Driver.SwitchTo().ActiveElement().SendKeys(
            "\"Q:\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Production\\01-Intro.mp4\""              
        );
```

The file is there and the path is correct but I catch:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'invalid argument: File not found : "Q:\OneDrive\Documents\Production\01-Intro.mp4\"

Any clues on how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly send the file location to the input element which handles the upload.

- driver.findElement(path to input).sendKeys(location of the file);

In your case try with one double quote:

> Driver.SwitchTo().ActiveElement().SendKeys("Q:\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Production\\01-Intro.mp4");

Comment: seems like it works but the open file dialog doesn't close. Should I do something to close the dialog explicitly?

Comment: just dont click on the button for import. sendkeys to input element directly uploads the file.